# How to get Total Storage Memory of all Spark executors via Custom Listener

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-2.0

I'm implementing custom spark listener in Java via:
`public class MetricsSparkListener extends SparkListener`
and want to capture Executor metrics as displayed in Spark history UI:
[Spark UI Executor Tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nyR5e.png)

Can someone please share some sample code or API documentation how to do this. I can't find any example on the web or any description.

I'm trying `onExecutorMetricsUpdate(SparkListenerExecutorMetricsUpdate executorMetricsUpdate)` but can't really get to contents of `ExecutorMetrics` object.
Call to `executorMetricsUpdate.executorUpdates().get().getMetricValue(ExecutorMetricType metricType)` requires ExecutorMetricType parameter which seems to be some Scala interface. Not sure what how to create metric type value.

Eventually I would like to reach to executor metrics described here [Available Executor Metrics](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/monitoring.html)
especially peak memory metrics and have them summarized for the whole app.